# Can't login (through GUI) after upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, login

After upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04 I can't login with my account through the GUI. If, at the login screen, I go to a command line I'm able to login and everything seems to work fine. I can also login as the guest account without any problems. But, logging in as my account causes a system freeze.

If I'm quick I can drop back to the command line, after starting graphical login process, and before the system freezes. If I do this I can check logs out and continue to use the system. But, when going back to the graphical session the system freezes immediately and I can no longer return to the command line.

System info: Linux x220r 3.2.0-24-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 25 08:43:22 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I also encrypted my home directory through the last (11.10) install. I suspected that might be a problem, but I can access my home directory fine while logging in through the command line.

Syslog taken right after starting a login from the login screen.

```
Apr 28 17:40:07 x220r sudo: pam_ecryptfs: pam_sm_authenticate: /home/matt is already mounted
Apr 28 17:41:43 x220r acpid: client 1093[0:0] has disconnected
Apr 28 17:41:43 x220r acpid: client connected from 1093[0:0]
Apr 28 17:41:43 x220r acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Apr 28 17:41:43 x220r kernel: [  142.913591] [drm:drm_mode_getfb] *ERROR* invalid framebuffer id
Apr 28 17:41:43 x220r kernel: [  142.913613] [drm:drm_mode_getfb] *ERROR* invalid framebuffer id
Apr 28 17:41:43 x220r kernel: [  143.000528] [drm] Changing LVDS panel from (+hsync, -vsync) to (-hsync, -vsync)
Apr 28 17:41:51 x220r lightdm: pam_ecryptfs: pam_sm_authenticate: /home/matt is already mounted
Apr 28 17:41:51 x220r kernel: [  151.180497] Valid eCryptfs headers not found in file header region or xattr region, inode 524953
Apr 28 17:41:51 x220r kernel: [  151.180507] Either the lower file is not in a valid eCryptfs format, or the key could not be retrieved. Plaintext passthrough mode is not enabled; returning -EIO
Apr 28 17:41:51 x220r kernel: [  151.226646] Valid eCryptfs headers not found in file header region or xattr region, inode 524953
Apr 28 17:41:51 x220r kernel: [  151.226649] Either the lower file is not in a valid eCryptfs format, or the key could not be retrieved. Plaintext passthrough mode is not enabled; returning -EIO
```

lightdm.log taken right after starting a login from the login screen.

```
[+1.47s] DEBUG: Connecting to XServer :0
[+1.47s] DEBUG: Starting greeter
[+1.47s] DEBUG: Started session 1342 with service 'lightdm', username 'lightdm'
[+1.59s] DEBUG: Session 1342 authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+1.59s] DEBUG: Greeter authorized
[+1.59s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log
[+1.59s] DEBUG: Session 1342 running command /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session /usr/sbin/unity-greeter
[+1.82s] DEBUG: Greeter connected version=1.2.1
[+1.82s] DEBUG: Greeter connected, display is ready
[+1.82s] DEBUG: New display ready, switching to it
[+1.82s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+2.40s] DEBUG: Greeter start authentication for matt
[+2.40s] DEBUG: Started session 1536 with service 'lightdm', username 'matt'
[+2.41s] DEBUG: Session 1536 got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+2.41s] DEBUG: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
```

Any ideas about things to look into? I hate to do this, but I've already pulled the files I want and I'm considering a clean reinstall.

**UPDATE:**

Looks like I'm suffering from this dual-monitor bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/921236

Unplugging my external monitor lets me log in. So far this is no confirmed fix, so I'm without an external monitor for the time being.

**UPDATE 2:**

I was able to fix the issue by downgrading xserver-xorg-input-evdev. More details here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/evdev/+bug/921236/comments/64

Answer (score 1):

I was glad to see the post and the UPDATE2. But I am completely at loss on how to fix it. From - https://launchpad.net/~sarvatt/+archive/sru1/+build/3118994

I installed the .deb package. After that, trying to install .udeb package, throws an error saying it couldn't replace a lib file already in .deb. Am I trying to do it right? Kindly help ! Below is the error when I ran dpkg install on the .udeb package:

```
dpkg: error processing xserver-xorg-input-evdev-udeb_2.6.99.901-1ubuntu3~lp921236_amd64.udeb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so', which is also in package xserver-xorg-input-evdev 1:2.6.99.901-1ubuntu3~lp921236
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xserver-xorg-input-evdev-udeb_2.6.99.901-1ubuntu3~lp921236_amd64.udeb
```